# Outbound Messaging and decimal fields

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

We are facing an issue with decimal fields while using outbound messages to an external system. Basically we are using outbound messaging for opportunity and sending few decimal fields to other systems via Integration. Now when the value in these field is larger than 8 characters, SFDC is adding 'E' to the value. e.g. if the Field value is 87,678,687.00 in SFDC, the value send in the outbound message is 8.7678687E7. Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to convert the value to a string and return text form the method and not a number? Maybe if the value is a string the system respect the format and it is not affecting for any conversion.